# How to convert click coordinates from one size of the picture to another?

Tags: javascript

I am writing an application in which I have to set some points on images. When 
I click on an image it creates a point(red square). The problem is that the image that I click on is actually resized. Let's say that original image's size is 1000x600 and resized 500x300. I want to load saved points on the original version but coordinates in my database come from resized version. I don't know how to resize values from my database to fit original version.

Comment: Possibly because it's tagged `javascript` but seems to have nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: Well, I see two possibilities. 5 minutes ago i got edit proposition(change 'i' to 'I'). Maybe it makes people angry. Second is I used java tag instead of javascript. ^^

Comment: I hadn't seen the tag. I think the solution for a bad tag in a question is to edit the question though, not downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, just normalize your coordinates. For example if your image is 500x400 and your point is at `(100, 50)`, instead of directly storing the point you can store `(0.2, 0.125)` because 100 is 20% of 500 and 50 is 12.5% of 400. Then, you can multiply these coordinates with whatever are the dimensions of the resized picture, that will give you a point that is roughly on the same spot on the image.

Comment: It's brilliant!! I didn't even think about it. Thank you!

Comment: No prob ^^ See ya